# "Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ",

Tags: java, mongodb

"Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ",

while fetching data from mongo .. what could be possible reason for this

Comment: Do you use lombok?

Comment: Yes i use lombok

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, It was the aggregation when unwind happened,Dont create the List of Object in Data object,

My previous class

```
Account{
        String _id;
          List<Transaction> trasactionList
       }
```

Corrected class

```
Account{
          String _id;
          Transaction trasactionList
    }
```

Comment: This might not be the solution. Your situation happened in the output class. It depends on the query where you create the output class

Comment: the query doesn't use aggregation..it simply fetch data with id